# MYSQL - Select não esta funcionando adequadamente

Tags: mysql

Boa noite,

Tenho abaixo a busca no banco de dados, mas ele me retorna erro ou não funciona na linha 4 onde diz "JOIN contratos co ON c.email != co.email", tem como fazer de outra forma, ou melhorar a busca? Obrigado

```
SELECT os.osID, c.nome, c.email, os.idioma, os.dataAtualizacao
    FROM os
JOIN cadastroCliente c ON os.idcliente = c.cadastroClienteID AND c.email != ''
JOIN contratos co ON c.email != co.email
    WHERE os.status = '1' 
    AND os.respondido = '1'
    AND os.emailAutRecuperar1 = '0'
    AND os.dataAtualizacao < CURRENT_DATE()-3
GROUP BY osID
```

Comment: qual erro aparece?

Comment: Na realidade não dá um erro, mas com o sem essa parte "JOIN contratos co ON c.email != co.email" mostra o mesmo numero de resultados...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este sinal: `!=`, não existe na sintaxe SQL padrão. [Até existe uma entrada no manual do MySQL com isso](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal), mas o recomendado, até por se aproximar do SQL ANSI, é usar `<>`, comum a todos os interpretadores SQL de qualquer tecnologia relacional.

Também é importante verificar se `c.email` não é nulo. Qualquer coisa comparado com nulo dá falso, exceto `is not null`.

O correto seria:

```
SELECT os.osID, c.nome, c.email, os.idioma, os.dataAtualizacao
    FROM os
JOIN cadastroCliente c ON os.idcliente = c.cadastroClienteID AND c.email <> '' and c.email is not null
JOIN contratos co ON c.email <> co.email
    WHERE os.status = '1' 
    AND os.respondido = '1'
    AND os.emailAutRecuperar1 = '0'
    AND os.dataAtualizacao < CURRENT_DATE()-3
GROUP BY osID
```